# Parse JSON value to an Activity from a ListView. Beginner

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I just learned java and also android app development.

I've been able to populate `json` object to a `listview` from a `web-service` to my `NewActivity.class`. but having problems with setting `OnItemClickListener` for my `listview` by parsing `json` value from my `jsonparser` class to my `DetailActivity.class`.

I tried reading some answers from here but got lost at some point. I Will be very glad if anyone makes an input. Thanks

JSON PARSER CLASS

```
public class JSONParser {

public static List<Events> parseFeed(String content) {

    try {
        JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(content);
        List<Events> eventList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(i);
            String headline = obj.optString("Content");

            Events events = new Events();

            events.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
            events.setTitle(obj.getString("Title"));
            events.setPostDate(obj.getString("PostDate"));
            events.setSummary(obj.getString("Summary"));
            events.setContent(obj.getString("Content"));
            events.setPicture(obj.getString("Picture"));
            eventList.add(events);
        }

        return eventList;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is my NewActivity.class.

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

final String LOG = "ListActivity";
private List<Events> eventsList;
private ListView lvEvents;
ProgressBar pb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    lvEvents = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if (isOnline()){
        requestData("http://json/events.php");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

protected void updateDisplay() {
    EventListAdapter adapter =  new EventListAdapter(this, R.layout.mylist_view, eventsList );
    lvEvents.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvEvents.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity.this, EventsDetail.class);
    intent.putExtra("selectedEvents", eventlist[position]);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void requestData(String uri){
    MyTask task = new MyTask();
    task.execute(uri);
}

protected boolean isOnline(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Events>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Events> doInBackground(String... params) {

        String data = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        eventsList = JSONParser.parseFeed(data);

        for (Events events : eventsList) {

            try {
                String imageUrl = events.getPicture();
                InputStream imageRead = (InputStream) new URL(imageUrl).getContent();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageRead);
                events.setBitmap(bitmap);
                imageRead.close();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return eventsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Events> results) {
        eventsList = results;
        updateDisplay();
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

And this my Events.class

```
public class Events implements Serializable  {

public int id;
public String Title;
public String PostDate;
public String Summary;
public String Content;
public String Picture;
public Bitmap bitmap;

public String getContent() {
    return Content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    Content = content;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPicture() {
    return Picture;
}

public void setPicture(String picture) {
    Picture = picture;
}

public String getPostDate() {
    return PostDate;
}

public void setPostDate(String postDate) {
    PostDate = postDate;
}

public String getSummary() {
    return Summary;
}

public void setSummary(String summary) {
    Summary = summary;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}
```

Lastly my DetailActivity.class which has three TextView to receive the JSON values

```
public class EventsDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TextView detailname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    TextView eventDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailContent);
    TextView eventDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailDate);

 }
```

Comment: You have to pass the selected event as a arguement in intent that you have created to invoke event detail activity thats all buddy :)

Comment: @Phrytz, have you tried my solution ?

Comment: yeah but maybe I'm not doing it right. I think you have to see how the NewActivity.class is constructed. I have edited my NewActivity.class have a look. @SandeepBhandari

Comment: @phrytz : buddy can you please post your NewActivity code :) I'll help you with declaring the array as a instance variable and then accessing it in onClick of list item :D

Comment: I have. check it @SandeepBhandari

Comment: @Phrytz : What is the issue now buddy ??? You should be able to access the array eventList in onItemClick right ?? is it crashing ?? What is the issue that you are facing now ?? :D

Comment: I dont see you implementing Events as Serializable in the question above ?? Have you declared Eents as Serializable using "implements Serializable" ??? I had posted a link as well to help you to declare Events as Serializable :)

Comment: I implemented the Serializable in my Events.class. Do I have to override some methods from the Serializable.class after implementing. @SandeepBhandari

Comment: @phrytze Nope :) what is the issue ?? is it crashing ?? what exactly is happening??

Comment: Yeah it crashes when I select an item on the list view.@SandeepBhandari

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, one other thing when ever I use "eventlist[position]" it give an error and ask me to convert it to "evenlist.get(position)" that gives me no error but the app crashes when I select the any item on the listview please is there any other way?

Comment: @phrytz : Buddy can you try one thing ?? just an experiment :) Can you please remove public Bitmap bitmap; from your Events class ?? and try passing events without bit map and tell me is ot working or not buddy :)

Comment: I hope its crashing because it has bitmap property :) I'll tell you how to deal with it later :) for now can you please confirm is the crash because of bit map by removing this property buddy ??? :)

Comment: I did as you said and still didn't work. I removed the Bitmap the Events.class  and also  from all the other class but didn't work

Comment: @phrytz : can you please post the crash log buddy :) and dont worry you will solve the issue soon :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, I have added the log, please check;

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.cana.www.myapplication.Events cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable

Comment: @phrytz : Hey buddy :) I have updated onItemClick :) please check if the update works for you :) I've left a comment as well :) If still have an issue lemme know :) I'll be happy to help you :D

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari: hey buddy it worked. It was the SDK and also the bitmap. Now it works without the bitmap. So how do I solve the bitmap problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :)

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity.this, EventsDetail.class);

    //try type casting Events instance as Serializable :)
    Events selectedEvent = eventList[position];
    intent.putExtra("selectedEvent",(Serializable)selectedEvent);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This will add selected event as an arguement to your intent :) which is responsible for invoking eventdetail activity :)

and in event detail activity :)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Events passedEvent = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selectedEvent");

    TextView detailname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    TextView eventDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailContent);
    TextView eventDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailDate);

    //set the textview values now from the recieved events instance :)
}
```

All being said :) for the above code to work you must implement implements Serializable to your Event class :)

This is very simple :) just requires you to specify implement Serializable and write setter and getter for all the properties of Events class :) Thats all :)

Here is a link for how to implement serialization :) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaSerialization/article.html

Hope my answer helped you :) Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: I implement the serialisable and already have the setter and getter but didn't work. And did you mean "intent.put" or "intent.putExtra", because "intent.put" gave me an error. and where from the "eventList[position]". Anyway thanks for your effort

Comment: hey Phrytz :) in your NewActivity.class there is a method named where you are declaring an adapter to which you are passing an array eventList as a parameter :) All you have to do is to declare a instance property for NewActivity and save this array in that property :) so that array can be accessed from all the methods in the class :) Dont have it as a local variable :) and yes you were right it is putExtra :) sorry for the mistake :) Din had android studio when I posted it :) So made a mistake :) I updated my answer :)

Comment: If you still have a problem leave a comment here buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to this way:

**1.** Make class `Serializable`

```
public class Events implements Serializable{

 // Other stuff

}
```

**2.** `onItemClick` of `ListView`.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity.this, EventsDetail.class);
    intent.putExtra("object",eventList[position]);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**3.** EventsDetail class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_detail);

   // Other stuff

    Events event = (Events) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("object");

}
```

Hope this will help you.